# Algorithm for minimizing the amount of lines to draw?

Tags: algorithm, autohotkey

I am currently working on optimizing a project of mine that is a few years old now. The purpose is to draw an image after hitting a certain combination of keys. The original version that I made a few years ago manually moved to each square section, but I've recently optimized it to draw rectangles for consecutive squares which makes it a lot faster.

The next step I want to take is optimizing the way the program draws a given layout, but I don't know where to start looking. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction since I can't even think of a search term for this.

Currently the program has a function called `Draw` which takes an input like this:

```
Invader =
(
00100000100
00010001000
00111111100
01101110110
11111111111
10111111101
10100000101
00011011000
)

Draw(Invader, 10) ; Where 10 is the size in pixels of each square
```

The layout above is for this image:

[image]

Draw will take that layout and draw it top to bottom, left to right in the following way:

[image]

In total, it takes 18 separate sections to finish the picture. What I'm looking for is some algorithm that can minimize this number. For instance, the following is one of the few ways of having only 16 sections:

[image]

Likewise, the difference between the current way and something I just made up on the spot for this image is 19 (65 compared to 46).

[image]

Where should I start with this?

Also for reference, here is the current Draw function:

```
Draw(Layout, BlockSize)
{
  Len := StrLen(Layout)                         ; Total amount of characters
  RowSize := StrLen(StrSplit(Layout, "`n")[1])  ; Size of a single row
  Index := 0

  While (Index < Len)
  {
    Length := 1
    Char := GetChar(Layout, Index)  ; Get next character in string

    if (Char == "1")
    {
      ; Get the number of consecutive 1s
      While (GetChar(Layout, Index + Length) == "1")
      {
        Length := Length + 1
      }

      ; Draw the rectangle
      FillRectangle(Length, BlockSize)
    }
    else if (Char == "0")
    {
      ; Get the number of consecutive 0s
      While (GetChar(Layout, Index + Length) == "0")
      {
        Length := Length + 1
      }

      ; Skip the entire length
      MouseMove, BlockSize * Length, 0, 0, R
    }
    else
    {
      ; End of line, reset position
      MouseMove, -(RowSize * BlockSize), BlockSize, 0, R
    }

    Index := Index + Length
  }
}

FillRectangle(Width, BlockSize)
{
  MouseGetPos, mX, mY
  mY2 := mY                     ; Same Y for straight line
  mX2 := mX + Width * BlockSize ; Add Width of rectangle times the block size to get final X position

  Loop %BlockSize%
  {
    ; Draw line
    MouseClickDrag, L, mX, mY, mX2, mY2

    ; Move to next line
    mY -= 1
    mY2 -= 1
  }

  ; Move mouse to next position
  MouseMove, 0, BlockSize - 1, 0, R
}

GetChar(String, Index)
{
  return SubStr(String, Index, 1)
}
```

Comment: that's the decomposition problem for rectilinear polygons. For polygons with holes there are only approximations known so far. And none of these algorithms is exactly simple to implement.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for giving a name to it. It does look quite a bit more difficult than I imagined, but I'll try to see what I can do with it. So far I haven't found anything covering polygons with holes in much detail which isn't promising.

Comment: i've found some resources. I'll comment the link when i'm at home

Comment: Why don't you use simple sprites for this? they should be way faster then this or you do not have fast pixels access at your disposal?

Comment: @Spektre I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean sprites for reading the layout? Parsing the layout? Showing the layout? This program doesn't work with images, so I don't think sprites would help.

Comment: may be that is the point... Your layout is a sprite. you are drawing single sprite by set of rectangles that is way too much overhead. I am not familiar with `autohotkey` (if it is meant to be used for this) or with what you are trying to do but if you have a sprite or texture and draw it with nearest neighbor and scale up by your grid size  you got the same output at single API call in most gfx APIs not to mention current HW is optimized for such operation. The rectangle calls could take more time then the drawing itself.

Comment: @Spektre I think there is a confusion on what the program is actually doing. It doesn't work on images, so there are no graphics APIs to call. It draws with the mouse by moving it around and drawing line segments. Here's an example that was recorded drawing in MSPaint: http://i.imgur.com/NEm1QEI.gifv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expanded from EpiGen's answer, but I felt it needed its own post to explain the differences.

This is the current status of what I have, but it's still not 100% optimal in all cases (as shown below). If there are any improvements feel free to add them.

So, the basic flow of the algorithm is as follows:

1. Get horizontal length from current point
2. Get vertical length from current point
3. Pick bigger length and use that direction

However, it doesn't just give the length it sees. Instead it picks the max length that doesn't intersect a line that has a greater length. Here are the steps:

1. Check if next pixel is a 1 (Going right for horizontal, down for vertical)
2. If it is, then check the length in the opposite direction starting from that index.
3. If that length is longer than the current length, then save the current length and the opposite length value.
4. Once a character that isn't a 1 is seen, if the max length in the direction being checked is lower than the max length in the opposite direction, then return the length in our direction before that point.

Here is an example of this logic in action. The grey lines represent lines that have already been drawn, the green line represents the line being checked, and the red line indicates a boundary.

[image]

Since the red line's horizontal length is greater than the current vertical length at this point, the values are saved in their current form (vertical 1, horizontal 7). After the vertical line check completes and finds a length of 2, it then sees that it crossed a line of length 7. Since it's less efficient to split this line for a smaller one, it instead changes its length back to 1 which is what it had before it crossed that line. That makes the final output look like this with a total of 16 segments, which is optimal as far as I know.

[image]

However, it fails under certain conditions; specifically the bottom left corner of this image.

[image]

The green line has a length of 10, and the row it stops at has a length of 9. Since that row isn't greater or equal to its size, it splits the line which leaves a single block to the side. If this problem were fixed, then this image would be optimal as far as I'm aware. (Lowest I've gotten is 44, current logic gets 45).

Regardless, this seems to be working as good as I need it to. If there are any other answers with better solutions in the next day or so I'll take a look at them.

As an extra, here's a gif of it running for one of the larger ones:

[image]

Comment: while I was reading I've got idea as well. I'll wait for the implementation of the last "fix" first xD

Comment: @EpiGen Feel free to mention it. I tested my idea and it gets the same number of segments even though it avoids the 1 block problem above.

Comment: My idea is to first run and detect boundary cells including lone cells. If cell is not alone it will have at least one direction to go (3 or 4 directions means somewhere in the middle - not our interest). Then (here comes complicated part) for each boundary cell found run the same algo (horizontal & vertical) and at once make checks if(cells[current] == "passed") { compare}... uh i'll better write prototype tomorrow. Already lost in my own thoughts :)

Comment: Could you provide images on which you made tests (other than existing)?

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but when I tested it out I still got 45 even after testing it several different ways. Specifically, the problem moves away from the left side single block to the right side single block. The only way around that is to ignore single blocks from the right side which gets 44, but it makes it look like a specific optimization for this one image which I don't think will translate to arbitrary ones. Also, not sure what you were asking for exactly but here is the Uboa image I've been using: http://i.imgur.com/fCD3hyS.png

Answer (score 1):

You should do some sort of analysis first either way. Afterwards I would propose to pass "image" both way and keep the longer line ( mark each cell of longer line as passed or "black" so you do not repeat checking).

```
void analyze(){
     var horSize = 0, verSize = 0;

     // run horizontally & vertically for each white cell
     while(!reached_boundary){
         ++horSize ;   
     }
     while(!reached_boundary){
         ++verSize ;   
     }
     someContainer.Add( (horSize > verSize) ? horSize:verSize);
}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, then it's a very simple way to get a better result. With the final image as a base I get 49 sections instead of 65. It's still worse than optimal, but it's a significant improvement. I'll probably use this for now until I can figure out how to improve it.

Comment: Maybe you already tried it. Instead of adding longer line add both results and at the end try out all combinations and fetch the one with the least sections. It will be far more complicated, at least for me. Marked as favorite, want to see that optimal sequence of actions as well :)

Comment: I've refined it so that the final image gets 46 sections which matches my initial guesswork solution. However, I found a more optimal solution which gets only 44, so it's still slightly sub-optimal. If I get it to work at 44 or below I'll post the solution.

Comment: I posted my version. After I finished posting it I came up with a new method that should fix the problem shown, so I will edit it whenever I implement that.